# How to add Excel web access web part in WSS 3.0

Tags: web-part, excel, wss

I'm new is SharePoint and struggling with adding web part. I'm using WSS 3.0. I want to add Excel Web Access Web Part, so I go to site Actions -> Web Part Gallery and try to upload .wdp file which looks like that.

```
    <WebPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
  <Assembly>Microsoft.Office.Excel.WebUI, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>
  <TypeName>Microsoft.Office.Excel.WebUI.ExcelWebRenderer</TypeName>
  <Title>Excel Web Access</Title>
  <Description>Use the Excel Web Access to interact with an Excel workbook as a Web page.</Description>
  <FrameType>TitleBarOnly</FrameType>
  <PartImageSmall>/_layouts/images/ewr023.gif</PartImageSmall>
  <PartImageLarge>/_layouts/images/ewr023.gif</PartImageLarge>
</WebPart>
```

After I uploaded web part, still couldn't use it. When I clicked on uploaded file, it  says:

**Cannot import this Web Part.**

Is Anything I'm doing wrong or not doing?

Answer (score 1):

you still need:
1. Microsoft.Office.Excel.WebUI in GAC
2. Microsoft.Office.Excel.WebUI namespace in SafeControls (WebConfig)
3. ewr023.gif in 14\IMAGES folder

and as far as I remember there should be installer for EWA which can do all the stuff for you